# inkscape SVG in, eps out produces raterization effects

Tags: svg, inkscape, eps

I am using Inkscape 0.48.2 r9819 on Windows 7

I have a very simple SVG file (jon.svg). It is just a black on white image of two overlapping ovals, with no effects. A closeup is shown here:

[Closeup of SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSPrO.png)

As you can see the SVG scales up properly when I zoom in. However, if I then use inkscape to convert that SVG to an EPS format (jon.eps) using the commandline,

inkscape.exe jon.svg -E jon.eps

I get what appears to be rasterization on the same image, seen here:

[Closeup of same area in EPS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/406RY.png)

Shouldn't EPS just encapsulate the vectorized image without having to do an rasterization? From what research I've done on the EPS format, it seems that it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it you are using to view the EPS file?  Could it be that?  Can you post the EPS file so we can see what is actually being produced?

Comment: I am using EPS Viewer. The SVG file I convert to EPS can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1iwaietu2rjdlq/jon.svg?dl=0

The resulting EPS output can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4t8xhmdtbjyozle/jon.eps?dl=0

FWIW I used potrace to convert  a BMP to the SVG file, but I don't see how that would matter... Thanks for getting back... Jon

Comment: The EPS file is fine.  Your EPS viewer is probably rendering the file to a bitmap, which you are then zooming into.  It must not be re-rendering the EPS contents when you zoom.